# NodeJS console logging, sporadic missing carriage return

Tags: node.js, logging, console

I can't seem to figure this one out.

I have tried multiple terminals.

I have a NodeJS application, that logs to a logfile and stdout, if a tty is attached. However, when logging to the terminal, sometimes the carriage returns are missing.

**Edit: I've got an MRE for this.**

```js
const util = require('util')
const exec = util.promisify(require('node:child_process').exec);

const { Worker, isMainThread, parentPort } = require('node:worker_threads');

async function run() {
  const worker = new Worker(__filename);
  console.log(`multiline\nfrom\nmain thread`);
  console.log({ mainThread: 'message', object: 555, here: 'aqui' })
  worker.postMessage({ worker: 'message' })
  worker.postMessage(`multiline\nstring\nhere\nbroken`)

  await exec('sudo iptables -L');
  console.log("this line will be in the middle of the screen")
  res = await exec('lsb_release -c -r -d');
  console.log(res.stdout);
  console.log({ mainThread: 'message', object: 555, here: 'aqui' });
  console.log('back\nto\nnormal\n\multiline');
}

if (isMainThread) {
  run()
} else {
  parentPort.on('message', (msg) => console.log(msg));
}
```

Will output the following:

[image: TerminalOutput]

if I comment out the `await exec('sudo iptables -L');` - it runs fine.

When this happens, sometimes it corrects itself after a few lines and the program continues on as normal. Other times, it continues to output with the missing carriage returns, and I can no longer use ctrl + c to stop the Node app, and have to use `kill`.

I understand that Node is single threaded, but that it uses `uvloop` for asynchronous actions, which can be multithreaded.

It seems to only be triggered by two logging actions at the same time. In the following example, I'm using an express app, with a middleware to log the request.

I'm using the logging module `winston` here, but I was getting the same result when using `console.log`

```js
const logger = (req, res, next) => {
  log.info(`\n\n${req.method}\n${req.url}\n${req.ip}\n`)
  next();
};
```

Then in another part of my code... I'm logging info about a firewall change. Here is the result:

```bash
info: Firewall adjusted inbound for ports: 80,443/tcp
info:

      GET
         /ws/443/.websocket
                           ::ffff:172.16.34.5

                                             info: Firewall adjusted outbound for ports: 80,443/tcp
```

You can see that the express log fired at the same time as the firewall adjusted log. Every time this happens, it breaks my terminal.

Other times, it will run, and the output is fine. So, I'm guessing some sort of timing issue.

What is the problem here, or, how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Something that is probably relevant, I'm using a log of child processes to run shell commands. I think that is somehow affecting the stdout of the parent process somehow???